# Backtrace retry only failed line content rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, exception

Am not sure its possible or not. In begin and rescue i want to retry only failed line not entire method in ruby on rails is it possible ?

```
def do_division_by_zero
  puts "start"
  puts (@ssp + 5).to_s
end

retries = 0
begin
  do_division_by_zero
rescue => e
  if (retries += 1) <= 3
    puts "Timeout (#{e}), retrying in #{retries} second(s)..."
    sleep(2)
    @ssp = 6 if retries == 2
    retry
  else
    e.backtrace.first(3) { |line| Rails.logger.error line }
  end
end
```

Output :-

```
start
Timeout (undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass), retrying in 1 second(s)...
start
Timeout (undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass), retrying in 2 second(s)...
start
11
```

Expected output :-

```
start
Timeout (undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass), retrying in 1 second(s)...
Timeout (undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass), retrying in 2 second(s)...
11
```

I want to retry only failed line not entire method is it possible in ruby on rails ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that is not possible because `retry` returns to the beginning of the block (to the `begin` in this example). See [docs](http://ruby-doc.com/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_expressions.html#UM).

When you want `retry` to start at a specific line then you have to structure your code in a way that only the line which can fail is in the `begin ... rescue` block.

In your example you could restructure it like this:

```
retries = 0
puts "start"

begin
  puts (@ssp + 5).to_s
rescue => e
  if (retries += 1) <= 3
    puts "Timeout (#{e}), retrying in #{retries} second(s)..."
    sleep(2)
    @ssp = 6 if retries == 2
    retry
  else
    e.backtrace.first(3) { |line| Rails.logger.error line }
  end
end
```

Please note that exceptions are very expensive operations and therefore it is worth it to avoid them if possible. In this example, it would be very easy to just check `@ssp` upfront and not let the code fail in the first place. But I guess it is just an example and your real code is more complex.